# vim起動の際、W18: Invalid character in group name が出力される

Tags: vim

vimを起動の際、画像の様に`W18: Invalid character in group name`が出力されます。
利用上、特に問題点などはありませんが、毎回出力されるので不安です。
解決法をご存知の方ご助言を宜しくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

この警告は syntax のグループ名に不正な文字が使われたことを知らせています。グループ名にはアルファベット、数字とアンダースコアしか使うことができません。

例: (グループ名に使えないハイフン(`-`)を使っています)

```
:syntax keyword foo-bar xxx
W18: Invalid character in group name
```

恐らく vimrc か、お使いのプラグインの中に問題を引き起こしているコードがあるのだと思います。ロードされたスクリプトの一覧は `:scriptnames` コマンドで見れるので、犯人を特定するのに役立ちます。

Comment: NERDTreeの拡張子のハイライト設定に問題があったようです。 @thinca